# when I don't have access to the Server how can i close the socket Connection from client side?

Tags: java, sockets

```
/*after socket.close(); socket.isConnected() returns "true" why ? */
package example.servertest;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;

public class ClientConn
{
   public void startClient()
   {
      String serverName = "localhost";
      int port = Integer.parseInt("8080");

      Socket client = null ;
      OutputStream outToServer = null ;
      DataOutputStream out = null ;
      try
      {
         System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName
                             + " on port " + port);
         client = new Socket(serverName,port);
         System.out.println("Just connected to "
                      + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
         outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
         PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(outToServer);
         pw.write("Hello ");
         pw.flush();
         pw.close();

         /*out =  new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
         out.writeUTF("Hello from "
                      + client.getLocalSocketAddress());*/
         /*InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
         DataInputStream in =
                        new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
         System.out.println("Server says " + in.readUTF());*/

      }catch(IOException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }finally{
          try {
              /* out.flush();
              out.close();
              outToServer.flush();
              outToServer.close(); */// closes the socket
              /*client.shutdownInput();
              client.shutdownOutput();*/

              client.close();
   System.out.println("isConnected : "+client.isConnected()+"\nisClosed : "+client.isClosed()+"\nisBound : "+client.isBound());

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
      }
   }
}
```

Description :
The Above code creates a "Socket Connection" from Apache Server and then close it..but after closing the Socket from client side it returns "socket.isConnected() = true".. I don't understand why?

Comment: Please read the documentation. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#isConnected()

Comment: No, the above code creates a *Socket* and connects it. There is no such thing as a 'SocketConnection' in the JDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket.isConnected() tells you whether you ever connected the socket. You did, so it returns true. It doesn't tell you anything about the state of the *connection,* of which the socket is an endpoint. Only reading an EOS does that.

Comment: thanks got it what u wanted to say..but my question is..as i have mentioned in the question that i don't have access to the server side code..how can i send a signal to server to close the socket connection from server side as well or is it okay to close the connection from client side only no need to send sny signal to server side ?

Comment: When you close your socket, the server will get -1 from read(), or some other EOS indication. Any correct network program will then close that socket.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about that. The link state will remain open for a while until it is being disposed. See Socket.isConnected in java doc:

```
public boolean isConnected()
Returns the connection state of the socket.
Note: Closing a socket doesn't clear its connection state, which means this method will return true for a closed socket (see isClosed()) if it was successfuly connected prior to being closed.
```

Comment: Meaningless. isConnected() has nothing to do with the link state beyond the initial connection operation.

Comment: @LynxZh : I didn't get what you are trying to say in terms of link state ..could you plz elaborate..

Comment: Sorry I missunderstand the document. I think now my understanding is that the "internal" is connected flag is still being set to true even if the socket is being closed. and the isConnected just return that flag.